# SQL Server After Update Trigger - Single Table - 2 Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (dbo.membersdatatable) that has multiple columns. I would like this trigger to update a column called "memberstatus" when "memberdesignation" is updated to a value of "10" from a value of "9".

-------SQL STATEMENT BELOW---------------

```
IF UPDATE([MemberDesignation])
--need to make it so it will recognize when memberdesignation = 10 
    UPDATE      dbo.MembersDataTable
    SET     MemStatus = '0'
    FROM        dbo.MembersDataTable AS mdtbl
    INNER JOIN  inserted AS i ON i.StudentID = mdtbl.StudentID
```

Comment: Your statement isn't a trigger.  Put all the logic you are using into the question.

Comment: As a general advice, avoid using triggers : it makes maintenance and evolution difficult. You probably have stored procedures to update your table, you should implement this buisness logic in a new stored procedure : something called like "usp_MemberStatusRules" and call this SP wherever you are interacting with the related data

Comment: ok so i am new at this SQL thing and this is all of the logic i have for this. what would a trigger OR SP look like for something like this?

Comment: @JulienR This is very controversial advise. In some cases it'is harder to maintain many procedures than one trigger. For example, when table is modified from many procedures.

Comment: @Igor Example : you debug/develop a SP : you can see what's going one, step by step : no confusion. If you have 1 trigger, ok you can be careful with it...let's say you have a complex SP and a few triggers running at the same time...it's going to be very very hard to follow. Plus, the problem with a trigger is that you have no idea how it's going to impact existing scripts. in an SP you can see what is happening.

Comment: @JulienR >>you can see what's going one, step by step<< In profiler you can see what triggers do. >>Plus, the problem with a trigger is that you have no idea how it's going to impact existing scripts.<< I don't see any difference between impact of other procedures or views or functions or indexes. Modifying any of them, you have to make sure that it will not hurt other objects.

Comment: @ Igor As you say, to know what's going on, you have to open the profiler...it add complexity, it gives you more things to take care of. "I don't see any difference between impact of other procedures or views or functions or indexes."  (indexes ???) A trigger can start in the middle of any process and change the data and mess with the rest of the process. In an SP, you change the data, you know it. maybe another ps will stop working but at least you can check the data and not have to figure out what and why a trigger is doing

Answer (score 0):

Use triggers SPARINGLY.  For example, my system has 138 tables, 550 stored procedures and only 28 triggers.  I wish I had less.

But if you decide a trigger is required, it will look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [t_MemberDesignationSideEffect] ON [dbo].MembersDataTable
FOR UPDATE 
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON  

IF NOT (    UPDATE([MemberDesignation])  ) RETURN

-- REMINDER: All triggers can and will fire for a set of rows...not just one

UPDATE mdtbl
SET     MemStatus = '0'
FROM  inserted i 
    JOIN dbo.MembersDataTable mdtbl on i.StudentID = mdtbl.StudentID
    JOIN deleted d on d.StudentID = mdtbl.StudentID
WHERE i.memberdesignation = '10'
and d.memberdesignation = '9'

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing an update trigger on table. Here you can use deleted and inserted magic tables. In case of update trigger:

*Deleted* table contains the row as it *was* before the UPDATE statement.
*Inserted* table contains the row as it *is* after the UPDATE statement.

```
create trigger update_member_status
on membersdatatable
for update
as
begin
    declare @old_designation int
    declare @new_designation int

    set @old_designation = (select memberdesignation from deleted)
    set @new_designation = (select memberdesignation from inserted)

    if (@old_designation = 9 and @new_designation = 10)
        begin
            update membersdatatable 
            set memstatus = '0'
            from membersdatatable as mdtbl
                inner join inserted as i on i.StudentID = mdtbl.StudentID
        end
end
```

Comment: It's going to work but definitively something I wouldn't like to have to debug... trigger + magic tables...that's tricky for someone new on sql and even for someone who knows about it

Answer (score 0):

You are going to update member status of all rows with a
memberdesignation = 10

you can probably add conditions to this query in order to update only the ones you want by using a date field or another

Simply call this procedure after updating your table

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_MemberStatusRules()
AS
    UPDATE      dbo.MembersDataTable
    SET     MemStatus = '0'
    WHERE memberdesignation = 10
    AND .....
    AND .....
GO
```